# Why "Mod Alias" does a redirect loop?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, alias

My config:

```
AliasMatch /browzerResources "/srv/default/browzerResources"

<Directory "/srv/default/browzerResources">
 Options Indexes MultiViews
 AllowOverride None
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>

</IfModule>
```

creates a redirect loop in the Web browser like this:

```
http://example.com/browzerResources/index.htm/index.htm/index.htm/index.htm/index.htm/etc...
```

Any idea why it does this?

Answer (score 1):

Because your *AliasMatch* will match anything including the specified path. My guess is that you want to use *Alias* instead?

```
Alias /browzerResources /srv/default/browzerResources
```